# How to program this in parallel?

Tags: c#, plinq

I am currently facing a performance problem with the following code.

```
private int globalType1 = 1;
private float globalType2 = 0.0342f;
private Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, float>> dt = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, float>>();

foreach (string file in Files) //assume 100 distinct files
{
    //GetType1AndType2 is thread safe
    Tuple<int, float> ift = GetType1AndType2(file, 0); //here 0 is the version of the file.

    if (ift.Item1 == globalType1 && ift.Item2 == globalType2)
    {
        dt.Add(file + "_0", fftandFreq); //Key = <FileName_Version> ; Value = Tuple<Type1, Type2>
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this in parallel.

Comment: Looks like this will be I/O bound (due to disk access) and therefore won't benefit much from parallelization (and in fact could become slower). But this depends on how much work is done in `GetType1AndType2()`, the code for which is not shown in your question.

Comment: So it is impossible to effectively answer this without more context about (1) the source of the files and (2) the implementation of `GetType1AndType2()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Parallel.Foreach`:

```
Parallel.Foreach(Files, file => 
{
    //GetType1AndType2 is thread safe
    Tuple<int, float> ift = GetType1AndType2(file, 0); //here 0 is the version of the file.

    if (ift.Item1 == globalType1 && ift.Item2 == globalType2)
    {
        lock (dt)
        {
            dt.Add(file + "_0", fftandFreq); //Key = <FileName_Version> ; Value = Tuple<Type1, Type2>
        }
    }
});
```

Make sure to lock your dictionary or use a thread-safe dictionary type. Whether this helps your performance or not depends on the actions take inside. If it is I/O based it might not benefit that much, but you can test that.

Comment: I think that trying to open and read many files in parallel is likely to make things slower (especially on a spinning rust drive).

Comment: If the file is located on several FTP servers for example it may benefit, but as said, it might not be fast at all. That is for OP to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it can be something like this

```
private Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, float>> dt = Files
  .AsParallel() // PLinq - parallel Linq
  .Select(file => new {
     ift = GetType1AndType2(file, 0),
     file = file})
  .Where(chunk => chunk.ift.Item1 == globalType1 && 
                  // Math.Abs(chunk.ift.Item2 - globalType2) < 0.00001
                  chunk.ift.Item2 == globalType2) 
  .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.file + "_0",
                chunk => chunk.ift); //TODO: check the value, please
```

But I doubt if the perfomance problem is actually in this code fragment. `Files` (*IO* operations are often *slow* ones) is the most probable source of the *perfomance* issue.

**P.S.** Comparing *floating point* values with `==` operation (`Item2 == globalType2`) is dubious because of *round up errors* (`float globalType2 = 0.0342f;` can well appear to be `0.0341999997` or `0.3420000002`). If you have to use `float` type (not `int`, `string` etc.), please, think on comparing with *tolerance*: change `chunk.ift.Item2 == globalType2` to `Math.Abs(chunk.ift.Item2 - globalType2) < 0.00001` or alike.